# Client-side javascript: be notified of all accesses to any property of Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, prototype, client-side

In javascript, or using the browsers's Dev Tools, is there a way to be notified or log or intercept all accesses to any property of `Object.prototype`?

What I'm trying to do is figure out all the places where some client-side code tries to access a property of an object that isn't defined anywhere in the inheritance chain. For example, if the code tries to access `someObject.xxx` and `xxx` isn't defined in `someObject`, I would like to be notified of that.

It can easily be done for a specific property or any object, by defining a getter for this property with `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'xxx', {get: _ => {...}})`. It can also easily be done for all properties of a specific object, using a Proxy. The question is, can it be done for any property of any object?

Comment: Except of `__proto__` (which does reference an object) there are only methods assigned to `Object.prototype`. How does the OP think could one intercept the attempted access of a property which not only does not exist at another object than `Object.prototype` but also does not exist at the latter itself? And a proxy does not help since its usage does not detect property accesses from other references than the proxy itself. There are also no error messages thrown as long as one does not invoke non existing methods. Thus one would need to know all possible property names / keys in advance.

Comment: @PeterSeliger yes I'm suspecting it's impossible with pure javascript (well I believe there were ways in the past, which were patched for security reasons), which is why I'm also asking if there's any way using using some debugging tool from the dev tools. Worst case, you could patch the browser, so there *has* to be a way; I'm wondering what the simplest way might be.